# iOS - Storyboard - cannot view embed in scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

I'm trying to set a scrollview.
One way is set scrollview on view but the option is disable. Check screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Another approach is select all subviews and embebed them on a scrollview but I will loose all my constraints.

Any simple solution to this situation?

Comment: Why downvote without explanation?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot embed the `Main View` to the `Scroll View`, instead you can take a `New View` and then Embed into a `Scroll View`.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without loose all contraints?

Comment: I can understand your worries, but nope, you have to embed all your elements into a `View` and then embed this `View` into a `Scroll View`. Although you can re-use all constraints except which are directly related/connected to the `Main View`.

Answer (score 0):

- Step one ---> Select your `view controller` in `storyboard`, then go to `size inspector`, change the `simulated size` to `freeform` and set the `height` as you need. `ex: 1000`.then it will show the actual size.
- step two ----> add `Scroll View` to your `Main view` and then add `constraints` to is(better to use `autolayout`).in here `constraints` should be `top`,`bottom`,`leading`,`trailing` to you `container/main view`.
- step three ---> then add another `view` to your `scrollview`. this is the `view` that hold your all other elements. and add `constrains` to the this view. `constraints` should be `top`,`bottom`, `leading`, `trailing` to the `scroll view` and `height` and `width` to the `view` `itself`.
- then `define` a `macro` ex: define `screenSize [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size` to get the device width. **(because at this point when you try to run, it show all good with height and scrolling, except the width.)** and `create` a `IBOutle` to your `view` `width`, that you added in previous step.
- final step ----> in you `viewDidLoad` method give the `constant` value to your `view` `width` like below.

  `self.myviewWidthConstraint.constant = screenSize.width;`

this will work fine for any device in portrait mode. if anyone wants to make this work in any mode(landscape and portrait) have to identify the `mode` change the `height` and `width`.
**note: then add you elements to your view and , add constraints. I think you have to setup all again**

for more, refer this link [how to setup scroll view for any device, and for any mode in ios.](https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=4433917978571273654#editor/target=post;postID=6854291368469577530;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=0;src=postname)